# Partial Differential Equations Function bilinear and continuos

Tags: functional-analysis

My problem is that I have $ q\in L^{N/2}$ and I must prove that $ a(u,v) = \int_\Omega quvdx$ is bilinear. To test this I must see $ \|a(u,v)\|\leq C |u|| v| $. But, I get here and I don't know how to limit it
$$ \int_\Omega |quv|dx $$
Where $a:H_0^1(\Omega)\times H_0^1(\Omega)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$. I have the idea of ​​using the Poincare or Sobolev inequality but I get the inverted inequalities. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for $N\ge 3$.
By Sobolev embedding, $H^1$ is continuously embedded into $L^p$ with $p=\frac{2N}{N-2}$ for $N\ge 3$. Using Hoelder inequality, we get
$$
|\int quv| \le \|q\|_{L^{N/2}} \|u\|_{L^p} \|v\|_{L^p} \le c \|q\|_{L^{N/2}} \|u\|_{H^1} \|v\|_{H^1}.
$$
Hoelder can be applied as $1/p + 1/p + 2/N = 1$.

For $N=2$, this is no longer true. Then $q\in L^1$ but $H^1$ is not embedded into $L^\infty$, so the integral $\int quv$ might not exist.